# org.XML.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@959e0aa)

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, domparser

I'm currently an intern at a company and they asked me to create an android app for a service they provide, for the app to work I need to read a settings file which is available through a soaprequest.

I already used a file like that once with other data and I had some problems but those were easily solved, this one however has been bugging me for the last hours.

I am getting this error:

```
03-18 10:57:30.775 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@959e0aa) 
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at com.example.stagiair.testomgeving.DomParser.buildDomDocument(DomParser.java:42)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at com.example.stagiair.testomgeving.dbTest$1.resultReady(dbTest.java:36)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at com.example.stagiair.testomgeving.HttpReader.onPostExecute(HttpReader.java:76)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at com.example.stagiair.testomgeving.HttpReader.onPostExecute(HttpReader.java:17)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-18 10:57:30.776 12815-12815/com.example.stagiair.testomgeving W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I know this has been asked here a lot of times but none of the answers provided seem to work for me. I've spent the last two hours looking for a solution but no progress whatsoever.

I can provide the XML structure but not the entire XML because it contains data I shouldn't just throw on the internet.

XML:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body xmlns="">
    <WebServerResponse>
      <Settings>
        <KantoorUren>
        </KantoorUren>
        <PersoneelData>
          <Persoon></Persoon>
        </PersoneelData>
        <MaterieelData>
          <Materieel></Materieel>
        </MaterieelData>
        <HulpMaterieelData>
          <HulpMaterieel></HulpMaterieel>
        </HulpMaterieelData>
        <AftekenDiensten>
          <Dienst></Dienst>
        </AftekenDiensten>
        <Statussen>
          <Status></Status>
        </Statussen>
      </Settings>
    </WebServerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**EDIT: Oh I forgot.. Here is the parser code**

```
     public void buildDomDocument (String newXml){
        String xml = newXml.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><").trim();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: I already used this parser with one xml and it worked, I will provide both XML files so you can maybe spot any differences.**

Working XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body xmlns="">
    <WebServerResponse>
      <Personeel>
        <PersonDetails>
          <Person>Ron Weasley</Person>
          <Mannummer>6</Mannummer>
          <NaamKort>Ron W</NaamKort>
          <Adres>Steenweg 2</Adres>
          <Woonplaats>WUUSTWEZEL</Woonplaats>
          <PostKode>3320 LL</PostKode>
          <Telefoon>04-94885522</Telefoon>
          <Uitwijktel></Uitwijktel>
          <Afdeling>0</Afdeling>
          <Email>wrwiz@gmail.com</Email>
        </PersonDetails>
        <BezettingPersoneel>
          <BezettingPersoneelDetail>
            <Datum>20160301</Datum>
            <Mannummer>6</Mannummer>
            <Omschrijving></Omschrijving>
            <Naam>Ron W</Naam>
            <Vertrektijd>7.30</Vertrektijd>
            <Aankomsttijd>16.30</Aankomsttijd>
            <Eindopdracht>16.00</Eindopdracht>
            <Contactuur>8.00</Contactuur>
            <Voorman>1</Voorman>
            <AfwVanUur>0.00</AfwVanUur>
            <AfwTotUur>0.00</AfwTotUur>
            <Act1VanUur>0.00</Act1VanUur>
            <Act1TotUur>0.00</Act1TotUur>
            <Act2VanUur>0.00</Act2VanUur>
            <Act2TotUur>0.00</Act2TotUur>
            <Act1PauzeV>0.00</Act1PauzeV>
            <Act1PauzeT>0.00</Act1PauzeT>
            <Act2PauzeV>0.00</Act2PauzeV>
            <Act2PauzeT>0.00</Act2PauzeT>
            <AgendaLijn>
              <RlNummer>21306</RlNummer>
              <Opname-nr>1</Opname-nr>
              <AgendaSeq>2</AgendaSeq>
              <ContactTijd>  `0 080000</ContactTijd>
              <ContactDatum>20160301</ContactDatum>
              <ContactUur>80000</ContactUur>
              <ContactDuur>8.00</ContactDuur>
              <MatAantal>2</MatAantal>
              <PersAantal>3</PersAantal>
              <Actie>26</Actie>
              <ContactOms>Move box to second floor</ContactOms>
              <Vertrektijd>7.30</Vertrektijd>
              <AankomstTijd>16.30</AankomstTijd>
              <Eindopdracht>16.00</Eindopdracht>
              <MaxDatum>0</MaxDatum>
              <OpnameDossier>
                <DossierNr>1160067</DossierNr>
                <RlNummer>21306</RlNummer>
                <OpnameNr>1</OpnameNr>
                <PerDatum1>20160301</PerDatum1>
                <PerDatum2>0</PerDatum2>
                <VolGeschat>35.000</VolGeschat>
                <VolEenheid>9</VolEenheid>
                <TotAfstand>0.000</TotAfstand>
                <TotColli>0.00</TotColli>
                <TotBrutoKg>0.00</TotBrutoKg>
                <TotNettoKg>0.00</TotNettoKg>
                <TotTarraKg>0.00</TotTarraKg>
                <TotBrutoLb>0.00</TotBrutoLb>
                <TotNettoLb>0.00</TotNettoLb>
                <TotTarraLb>0.00</TotTarraLb>
                <TotVolCbm>0.000</TotVolCbm>
                <TotVolCft>0.000</TotVolCft>
                <TotVolGew>0.000</TotVolGew>
                <Beheerder>76</Beheerder>
                <Zoeknaam>NORTHMAN</Zoeknaam>
                <DebiteurNr>25669</DebiteurNr>
                <SrtVerhuis>1</SrtVerhuis>
                <Goederen></Goederen>
              </OpnameDossier>
              <AdressenPerAgenda>
                <AdresDetail>
                  <Rlnummer>21306</Rlnummer>
                  <OpnameNr>1</OpnameNr>
                  <AdresSeq>2</AdresSeq>
                  <typeVAdres>9</typeVAdres>
                  <Naam1>Mister H. Clint</Naam1>
                  <Naam2></Naam2>
                  <Naam3></Naam3>
                  <BezoekAdres1>Henkseweg 44</BezoekAdres1>
                  <BezoekAdres2></BezoekAdres2>
                  <BezoekAdres3></BezoekAdres3>
                  <PostCodeBez>2260 EK</PostCodeBez>
                  <BezoekPlaats>RUURGEM</BezoekPlaats>
                  <Land>0</Land>
                  <Taal>0</Taal>
                  <Transporteur>0</Transporteur>
                  <ChauffeurNr>0</ChauffeurNr>
                  <ChauffeurVr></ChauffeurVr>
                  <KentekenNr>0</KentekenNr>
                  <KentekenVr></KentekenVr>
                  <ChassisNr>0</ChassisNr>
                  <ChassisVr></ChassisVr>
                  <VmedNummer></VmedNummer>
                  <VmedType>0</VmedType>
                  <VmedStatus>0</VmedStatus>
                  <Seal></Seal>
                  <BoekingsRef></BoekingsRef>
                  <GevrDatum>0</GevrDatum>
                  <GevrUur>0.00</GevrUur>
                  <GeplDatum>0</GeplDatum>
                  <GeplUur>0.00</GeplUur>
                  <WerkDatum>0</WerkDatum>
                  <WerkUur>0.00</WerkUur>
                  <WerkDuur>0.00</WerkDuur>
                  <Country>NL</Country>
                  <Language></Language>
                </AdresDetail>
              </AdressenPerAgenda>
            </AgendaLijn>
          </BezettingPersoneelDetail>
        </BezettingPersoneel>
      </Personeel>
    </WebServerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Failing XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body xmlns="">
    <WebServerResponse>
      <Settings>
        <KantoorUren>
          <AM_FROM>06:00</AM_FROM>
          <AM_TILL>12:00</AM_TILL>
          <PM_FROM>13:00</PM_FROM>
          <PM_TILL>20:00</PM_TILL>
        </KantoorUren>
        <PersoneelData>
          <Persoon>
            <Person>Frank Jackson</Person>
            <Mannummer>235</Mannummer>
            <NaamKort>Frank J</NaamKort>
            <Naam>Frank Jackson</Naam>
            <Adres></Adres>
            <Woonplaats></Woonplaats>
            <PostKode></PostKode>
            <Telefoon></Telefoon>
            <Uitwijktel></Uitwijktel>
            <Email></Email>
          </Persoon>
        </PersoneelData>
        <MaterieelData>
          <Materieel>
            <Materieelnr>22</Materieelnr>
            <Kenteken>GHP-235</Kenteken>
            <Omschrijving>Truck</Omschrijving>
          </Materieel>
        </MaterieelData>
        <HulpMaterieelData>
          <HulpMaterieel>
            <Code>Cart. Box</Code>
            <Omschrijving>Cartboard Box</Omschrijving>
            <Volgnummer>2</Volgnummer>
          </HulpMaterieel>
        </HulpMaterieelData>
        <AftekenDiensten>
          <Dienst>
            <Code>101</Code>
            <Omschrijving>Retreived necklace</Omschrijving>
          </Dienst>
        </AftekenDiensten>
        <Statussen>
          <Status>
            <Volgorde>1</Volgorde>
            <Code>12</Code>
            <HoofdStatus>Stop</HoofdStatus>
            <SubStatus></SubStatus>
            <Omschrijving>Stop</Omschrijving>
            <LetterCode>S</LetterCode>
            <Kleurcode>22</Kleurcode>
          </Status>
        </Statussen>
      </Settings>
    </WebServerResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my parser code to this:

```
     public void buildDomDocument (String newXml){
        String xml = newXml.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><").trim();
        Log.e("XML: ", xml);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            byte[] bytes = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(xml).array();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Apparently, or at least what I got out of this, was that the UTF-8 encoding went wrong somewhere in the process and it didn't on the other XML files, but using this code solved that.

Now it works.

If anyone can clarify how this could have happened or what this does exactly, feel free to do so.